# How to throw threads from one for loop?

Tags: java, java-threads

It does not create nor launch more than one thread.

I tried to make the poller class to implement runnable and invoke it with run(). Also made it extend from thread and invoke it with start(). I added System.out.println(i) within the caller function pollRows() and it just prints "1".

```
public void pollRows() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            Poller rowPollerThread = new Poller(port, rows[i]);
            rowPollerThread.start();                             
        }
    }


public class Poller extends Thread {

private static byte[] pollerBytes = {
    (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0xc9
};

private static byte[] polledBytes;

private static com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort serialPort;

private static Row row;

public Poller(com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort serialPort, Row row) {
    this.serialPort = serialPort;
    this.row = row;
}

@Override
public void start() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            getHelioStates();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Poller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private static void getHelioStates() throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < row.getHeliostats().length; i++) {            
        writeFrame(i);
        readByteFrame();
        setHelioStates(row.getHeliostats()[i]);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}

private static void writeFrame(int i) {
    pollerBytes[0] = (byte) row.getAddresses()[i];
    serialPort.writeBytes(pollerBytes, 8);
}

private static void readByteFrame() {
    polledBytes = new byte[serialPort.bytesAvailable()];
    serialPort.readBytes(polledBytes, polledBytes.length);
}

private static void setHelioStates(Heliostat heliostat) {        
    for (int i = 0; i < polledBytes.length; i++) {            
        Byte b = polledBytes[i];
        heliostat.bytePosition(i, b);
    }
}
```

}

It only creates and launch the first thread, the output from the launched thread is as expected.

Comment: You need `start()` instead of `run()` to make new threads. But you say you tried that. So what happened? Any errors? How do you know that there are no extra threads? Can you add some `System.out.println()` for debugging before your infinite loop? What does `getHelioStates()` do?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the fact that the launched thread never finish since the run method contains a bucle while(true)

Comment: does getHelioStates block?
in any case just add log in last line of for loop. you will see how many threads are started

Comment: What is wrong with the [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)? Are there any specific reason for reinventing the wheal ?

Comment: "I guess it has something to do with the fact that the launched thread never finish since the run method contains a bucle while(true)" no, it is because you never start/launch another thread. call `start()` not `run()`

Comment: No erros when I used start() just the same behavior, I added a sout(i) with the iterator variable i and it only prints "1".
getHelioStates() writes and read a serial port and apparently does it fine.

Comment: Did you also override `start()`? Because that's not good idea. Best to not `extends Thread` at all, just `implements Runnable`.

Comment: If getHelioStates is synchronized then all of your threads can block on the one method. Can you update your code with what you're currently running, and explain the output?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the call to `getHelioStates()` (replace it with print + sleep)?

Comment: Your latest code still has `run()`. Please update and confirm that you did try `start()`.

Comment: start will launch new call of stack, run() will execute in the current thread.

Answer (score 2):

Don't override start method of Poller class because start method causes thread to begin execution. You should override run method.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            getHelioStates();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Poller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it, many thanks to all of you.

Comment: Don't extend Thread at all. Implement Runnable. Give that Runnable to an Executor (or if you absolutely must, do `new Thread(myRunnable)`)

Answer (score 0):

Your threads aren't working correctly because you haven't defined a `run()` method.

Javadoc for `Thread` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) explains the two ways to create a new thread:

- declare a class to be a subclass of Thread. This subclass should override the run method of class Thread.
- create a thread is to declare a class that implements the Runnable interface. That class then implements the run method.

Both should be started by calling the `start()` method (which you were correctly doing), however both also require that you implement `run()` to define your thread's behavior (which is not in your code above).

It might help to add some printed output to your `run()` method, like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("thread " + this.getName() + " is now running");
    // do other things in thread
}
```

That will show you that all of your threads are created, and also shows that the sequence in which you call `start()` is not the same sequence in which `run()` is called.